# Doc inside the collection appears in italic font while saving into firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
try {
  // create a collection called 'pactLists'
  const pactListsCollection = collection(db, "pactLists"); // for keeping the records of created pacts by all users.

  // generate a unique id for the creating pact , it will be the invite code for that pact as well.
  const uniquePactId = uuidv4();
  setInviteCode(uniquePactId);

  // Create a document reference to the 'pactLists' collection with the uniquePactId
  const pactListDocRef = doc(pactListsCollection, uniquePactId);

  const creatorDetails = {
    address: account,
  };
  // Set the creatorDetails inside the 'pactLists' collection
  await setDoc(pactListDocRef, {
    creator: creatorDetails,
    // joiners: [], // Initialize an empty array to store joiner details
  });

  // Document updated successfully in pactLists
  console.log("pact details document successfully updated!");

  const memberDetails = {
    address: account,
    minimumPledgeAmount: enteredPledgeAmount,
    frequentPledging: selectedPledgeFrequency,
    pledgingDuration: selectedPledgeTerm,
  };
  // datas to set inside the createdPactDetails collection.
  const pactDetailsToSet = {
    pactName: pactName,
    membersCount: minMembers,
    inviteCode: uniquePactId,
    minimumPledgeAmount: minEthPledge,
    frequentPledging: selectedPledgeFrequency,
    pledgingDuration: selectedPledgeTerm,
    pactCreationDeadline: deadline,
    creatorId: account,
    joinStatus: "Waiting for other members to join",
    members: [memberDetails],
  };

  // Now, create the 'userPacts' collection
  const userPactsCollection = collection(db, "userPacts");
  // Create a document reference to the 'userPacts' collection using the user's MetaMask account address
  const userPactsDocRef = doc(userPactsCollection, account);

  // Create the 'AdminPacts' subcollection
  const adminPactsCollection = collection(
    userPactsDocRef,
    "AdminPacts"
  );
  // Create a document reference to the 'AdminPacts' subcollection using the uniquePactId
  const adminPactDocRef = doc(adminPactsCollection, uniquePactId);

  // Set the pactDetailsToSet inside the 'AdminPacts' subcollection
  await setDoc(adminPactDocRef, pactDetailsToSet);
  // Document updated successfully in 'AdminPacts'
  console.log(
    "AdminPact document successfully updated!",
    pactDetailsToSet
  );

  // Now, create the 'JoineePacts' subcollection
  const joineePactsCollection = collection(
    userPactsDocRef,
    "JoineePacts"
  );
  // Create a document reference to the 'JoineePacts' subcollection using the uniquePactId
  const joineePactDocRef = doc(joineePactsCollection, uniquePactId);

  // Set the pactDetailsToSet inside the 'JoineePacts' subcollection
  await setDoc(joineePactDocRef, memberDetails);

  // Document updated successfully in 'JoineePacts'
  console.log(
    "JoineePact document successfully updated!",
    memberDetails
  );
  setModalPageNumber(2);
} catch (error) {
  console.log("Error updating pact creation document: ", error);
}
```

This is how I am creating new collection and storing the data into my firebase account, but inside the collection "userPacts" the doc that I am referring in the following line : `const userPactsDocRef = doc(userPactsCollection, account);` seems to be stored in italic font. Why this happens?

Also I was trying to fetch the details in my another component as follows:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Checking pact for account:", account);

  const checkUserPact = async () => {
    try {
      const userPactsCollection = collection(db, "userPacts");
      const userPactDocRef = doc(userPactsCollection, account);

      const userPactDoc = await getDoc(userPactDocRef);

      if (userPactDoc.exists()) {
        // User has a pact, you can use the data if needed
        console.log("User has a pact.");
        setUserHasPact(true);
      } else {
        // User does not have a pact
        console.log("User does not have a pact.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error checking user pact:", error);
    }
  };

  checkUserPact();
}, [account]);
```

even if the user account have created a pact, it shows "User does not have a pact."

I want to fix the issue with doc saving in italic format while saving into firebase also, I want to fetch the details if the user has any "adminPacts" inside the "userPacts" collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does **not** create a document in the database:

```
const userPactsDocRef = doc(userPactsCollection, account);
```

Instead it merely creates a reference to a path in the database where a document may or may not exist.

If you want a document to exist at `userPactsDocRef`, you will need to [write to the path](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document). Something like this:

```
await setDoc(userPactsDocRef, {
  createdAt: Date.now()
});
```

Comment: Well! this worked! Thanks for the help